# How to get jsp:useBean Value in javascript without using hidden field?

Tags: javascript, jsp

Here is my jsp snippet

```
  <jsp:useBean id="beamManupulate" class="com.tfl.beam.BeamManipulator"     scope="session" />
<jsp:setProperty name="pcBean" property="pageno" value="<%= pageNumber%>"/>
```

How can i get the value of `pageno` in javascript code ?

Some of the solutions here say to use hidden field. But i dont want to use them.

Any other solutions ?

Comment: For the JSP, JavaScript is the same as HTML code: it's text that must be generated and sent to the browser. Why do you use jsp:useBean, jsp:setProperty and scriptlets in the first place? Those are obsolete and shouldn't be used for more than 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

See, initially you are getting the value of `pageno` from `<%= pageNumber%>`.

So, you can directly assign that variable's value in script variable like below:

```
var pageno = '<%= pageNumber%>';
```